# How to get ilo gen/version

Tags: redhat, hp-proliant, ilo

Im trying to find a way to get the ilo gen, currently our blades are a mix of ilo versions/generations.
When I run:

curl https://someip/rest/v1/Systems/Processors -i -u ilo-admin:[somepassword]--insecure -L

I get the message:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 119
Date: Tue, 14 May 2019 14:05:17 GMT
Server: HP-iLO-Server/1.30
```

Which shows me that the version is 1.30
But how can i find out which generation it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a URI that gives both the generation (iLO 3, iLO 4, etc.) and the firmware version.

```
curl -k https://10.2.0.101/xmldata?item=All
```

(Tested on iLO 3 and iLO 4.)

Example output for iLO 3:

> ...
>
> <PN>Integrated Lights-Out 3 (iLO 3)</PN>
>
> <FWRI>1.87</FWRI>
>
> …

Example output for iLO 4:

> …
>
> <PN>Integrated Lights-Out 4 (iLO 4)</PN>
>
> <FWRI>2.53</FWRI>
>
> …

So you should be able to use Curl, and then pull the <PN> and <FWRI> elements.